# Showing Images in Custom JTable dynamically

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am displaying custom class objects, like personal data in a JTable.
My JTable, therefore, has a custom Table Model that gives each column the same object. So in my Custom Cell Renderer, the data, which I want to show in the specific column is delivered by the class object.
In this Table, there is also a column for an image for each object, which is fetched from an apache tomcat database.
So far the display of the picture works really fine but which a larger amount of images I get so many problems. The loading of the images before creating the JTable takes too much time. So I created a special IamgeLoader which keeps all the Images and by passing my object to this loader I get the image to show in the table.

Now to my problem: To fetch all the pictures, the image loader is filled with images in a separated thread, therefore I use a SwingWorker which also works fine. So the question is how can I update the images in the JTable. I want that the images are "added" step for step. Any ideas on how to get a solution with a good performance.
Maybe I'm totally on the wrong way and there will be a much more simple or better way to do this.
Thanks

EDIT: For making my problem clearer I created a simple example. This is just simple and I know that there are a lot of things missing. But maybe you could give me some tips and tricks. This only shows the way I want to go. The fillImages method should run in the background and with a large number of pictures, it will still load pictures when the table is already created. So what's the right way to update these pictures?

```
public class TablePerson extends JFrame
{

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    public static ImageLoader loader_ = null;



    public static void main( String [ ] args )
    {
        TablePerson frame = new TablePerson( );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }


    public TablePerson( )
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setBounds( 100, 100, 450, 300 );
        contentPane = new JPanel( );
        contentPane.setLayout( new BorderLayout( 0, 0 ) );
        setContentPane( contentPane );

        Person p1 = new Person( 20, "John", null );
        Person p2 = new Person( 25, "David", null );
        Person p3 = new Person( 50, "James", null );

        Vector< Person > personList = new Vector< Person >( );
        personList.add( p1 );
        personList.add( p2 );
        personList.add( p3 );

        loader_ = new ImageLoader( personList );

        PersonTableModel model = new PersonTableModel( personList );

        table = new JTable( model );
        table.getColumnModel( ).getColumn( 0 ).setCellRenderer( new mTableRenderer( loader_ ) );
        table.getColumnModel( ).getColumn( 1 ).setCellRenderer( new mTableRenderer( loader_ ) );
        table.getColumnModel( ).getColumn( 2 ).setCellRenderer( new mTableRenderer( loader_ ) );
        contentPane.add( table, BorderLayout.CENTER );
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int age_ = 0;
        public String name_ = null;
        public ImageIcon picture_;

        public Person( int age, String name, ImageIcon picture )
        {
            age_ = age;
            name_ = name;
            picture_ = picture;
        }
    }

    public class PersonTableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        protected Vector persons_ = new Vector( );

        public PersonTableModel( Vector< Person > persons )
        {
            persons_ = persons;
        }

        @ Override
        public int getColumnCount( )
        {
            return 3;
        }

        @ Override
        public Object getValueAt( int rowIndex, int columnIndex )
        {
            return persons_.get( rowIndex );
        }

        @ Override
        public int getRowCount( )
        {
            return persons_.size( );
        }
    }

    static public class mTableRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer
    {
        private ImageLoader loader_ = null;

        public mTableRenderer( ImageLoader loader )
        {
            this.loader_ = loader;
        }

        @ Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent( JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column )
        {
            Person person = ( Person ) value;
            JLabel label = null;

            if ( column == 0 )
            {
                label = new JLabel( person.name_ );
            }
            else if ( column == 1 )
            {
                label = new JLabel( Integer.toString( person.age_ ) );
            }
            else if ( column == 2 )
            {
                label = new JLabel( "" );
                label.setIcon( loader_.getImage( row ) );
            }

            return label;
        }

    }

    public class ImageLoader
    {
        private List< ImageIcon > images_ = new ArrayList< ImageIcon >( );

        public ImageLoader( Vector< Person > data )
        {
            fillImages( data );
        }

        private void fillImages( Vector< Person > data )
        {
            final Vector< Person > dataFinal = data;
            SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker< List< ImageIcon >, Void >( )
            {

                @ Override
                protected List< ImageIcon > doInBackground( ) throws Exception
                {
                    for ( Person person : dataFinal )
                    {
                        // Just a example picture, later here different images
                        images_.add( new ImageIcon( ImageIO.read( new File(
                                "C:\\Work\\Eclipse Luna\\TestProject\\src\\me\\testproject\\calendar.png" ) ) ) );
                    }
                    return images_;
                }
            };
            worker.execute( );
        }

        private ImageIcon getImage( int index )
        {
            return images_.get( index );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My "personal" thought is, each image request should have an associated `id` (like the "row") so that the `TableModel` can find the row associated with it.  When you load an image, you use the `process`/`publish` mechanism to deliver the said message to the `TableModel`, the `TableModel`, using the `id` and `image`, finds the row, applies the `Image` to it and generates a `TableModel` event stating which row/column was updated.  If you do it right, you could make a single `SwingWorker` which loads a single `Image` and then fill a `ExecutorService` with them and let it run!

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer, I added some example code to my question. So maybe you could tell me which parts I should change.